# PHP How to Redirect to Another Page with Apache Server?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to another page:
The idea is to create a submit button for user to click on it, then redirect to another page that also has the database records (MySQL Database).

Update: I'm using SELF PROCESSING form and with SEVERAL SUBMIT BUTTONS that have different functionality.

Here's my code with problems:

```
//Redirect and for user to delete particular record(s)
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $query="DELETE FROM Student WHERE StudentId='$id'";
    $qresult=mysqli_query($link,$query);
    if($qresult){
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        $redirect='/RedirectedPage.php';
        header('Location:'.$redirect,true,303);
        exit;
    }                   
}
```

As you can see, I'm doing it with header() but it doesn't redirect, 
instead, the current page only refreshed itself.

The database linked successfully, query seems ok...

Therefore, I'm wondering what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just submit your form to another page

```html
<form action="delete.php">
  
  <input name="delete" type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
```

so your php code should be in the delete.php file

you can also change your code to this

```html
//Redirect and for user to delete particular record(s)
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $query="DELETE FROM Student WHERE StudentId='$id'";
    $qresult=mysqli_query($link,$query);
    if($qresult){
        
        header("Location: RedirectedPage.php");
        exit;
    }                   
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to specific that because I'm using a self processing php form with several submit buttons. I'm not sure about this..

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm sorry